# MVC Html.Raw empty in Html.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the controller, I assign a string to ViewBag:

HomeController:

```
ViewBag.Parameters = "new { needSearch = true }";
```

Then in the View, I did this:

```
@Url.Action("doSearch", Html.Raw(ViewBag.Parameters))
```

Then I took a look at the development tools, the output was

```
/Home/doSearch
```

and the querystring (i.e. needSearch=true) is missing

I did another test, and I did this to check if it can print the ViewBag:

```
 @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Parameters)
```

And the above code output the disired result:

```
needSearch=true
```

I made a fiddle sample:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FF1iGV

As you see in the sample

If I call `@Url.Action("doSearch", Html.Raw(ViewBag.Parameters))`, the querystring is missing

What is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand you talk about string then you use boolean

Comment: May I ask why you are putting that in the viewbag? It's not going to render it like that.

Comment: The second parameter of `@Url.Action()` is a `RouteValueDictionary` (or object defining the routes) but you have defined the `ViewBag` property as a `string` - `ViewBag.Parameters = "new { needSearch = true }";`

Comment: @Glitch100 Actually I would like to generate the query string dynamically, so I can't hardcode the querystring in the View...

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you mean I have to store a RouteValueDictionary in the ViewBag instead of a string?

Comment: @clement I mean, I stored a string in a ViewBag, anything I was unclear in the question..??

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because the search criteria is stored in the database, so everytime when the page loads, I have to fetch data from database to generate the querystring dynamically.

Comment: @User201384 storing "new { needSearch = true }" as string makes me feel dirdy for you :-)

Comment: @User2012384, Then do it all on the controller instead of this half and half approach. `ViewBag.myUrl = Url.Action("doSearch",  new { needSearch = true } })'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your code ViewBag.Parameters is a string type so it will take as controller name. Try this

```
ViewBag.Parameters = new { needSearch = true };

@Url.Action("actionname", ViewBag.Parameters);
```